# Encrypt a file with 2 certificates

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, smime

Normally we encrypt files with opennssl. This is how we do it.

```
openssl smime -encrypt -binary -aes256 -in file.cfg -out file.cfg.enc -outform der cert1 cert2
```

Can someone give me a hint please how to do it in c#?

thank you.

Comment: Find a relevant library and look at the documentation?

Comment: If you want to use openssl, then use it. Write a command line wrapper, capture the output and provide the API you need...

Comment: Please don't ask for a tutorial. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1):

You want [EnvelopedCms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.envelopedcms(v=vs.110).aspx), which may require that you add a reference to System.Security.dll.

```
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(File.ReadAllBytes("file.cfg"));

CmsRecipientCollection recipients = new CmsRecipientCollection
{
    new CmsRecipient(new X509Certificate2("cert1")),
    new CmsRecipient(new X509Certificate2("cert2")),
};

EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms(
    content,
    new AlgorithmIdentifier(new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42")));

envelopedCms.Encrypt(recipients);
File.WriteAllBytes("file.cfg.enc", envelopedCms.Encode());
```